# ColdFusion CFHTTP GET strips cookie

Tags: web-services, coldfusion, coldfusion-9

I'm running into issues trying to pass a cookie in my CFHTTP GET Statement.

Has anyone else experienced this?   Pointers would be appreciated.  BTW - I am using the `x-http-method-override`, because I saw this on a few other sites that were discussing this topic.

```
<cfhttp url="#this.apiServer#/api/v#this.version#/user.json" 
        method="POST" result="jorn">            
    <cfhttpparam type="COOKIE" name="ms_user" value="#arguments.patAppSession#" />
    <cfhttpparam type="header" name="Content-Type" value="application/json" />
    <cfhttpparam type="header" name="x-http-method-override" value="GET" />
    <cfhttpparam type="body" value='#variables.dataFields#' />
</cfhttp>
<cfdump var = "#jorn#">
```

Comment: You're "running into issues." What is the specific issue?

Comment: the service I'm calling isn't recognizing that there is a cookie.   So I'm getting an unauthorized user error when I attempt the GET

Comment: The code you have above is a POST request. It should not matter either way, but please ensure that you did post the code you intended to

Comment: The best way to determine if it is CF not sending the cookie or the server a potential problem with formatting is to use a proxy to intercept the request and see if the cookie is being sent.  Install a proxy on the server and route the cfhttp request through it using the proxyserver and proxyport attributes.